# Using testnet with Nami

Tags: testnet, nami

I want to test a dapp on the Prepod testnet with the Nami wallet. I tried to receive tAda with the faucet but nothing is showing up on the wallet interface.

This is the wallet
addr_test1qrgupcpekj8x5wzw4kk37g38eceh9wdyqeap3puky8yy2k5zpumumlqxeggrg9ezllhhnyrqr892v5tdevccaz780d8s7kw9xp

This is the tx hash
c5a3c23285e44688643f79d2be08ae54e50812e6fe6857028260ff80380ea6a0

What can I do to fix the Nami interface? Or what wallet can I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currently released version of Nami runs on the old testnet, but here's a vasil-ready branch of it, that you can install separately for testing on the preprod (or preview) testnet:

https://github.com/berry-pool/nami/tree/vasil

You can download the build from [here](https://github.com/berry-pool/nami/blob/vasil/build.zip) and

> Extract the zip. Then go to chrome://extensions, click Load unpacked
> at the top left and select the build folder.

Answer (score 0):

Until Nami adds support for pre-prod testnet you'll need to use a wallet that already supports it, like Eternl.